# How to read each row and value with SqlCommand in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to using C# and am now messing around with SQL Server connections. My connection is working and I can run queries, I just can't view any of the data that is returned. I've seen that you need to run `command.ExecuteReader()` to get the data back but I cannot get any other data than the first column and row.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="biquery_query" %>
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class biquery_query : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        var query = context.Request.QueryString["query"];
        query = "SELECT * FROM [hidden].[dbo].[hidden]";

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=hidden;Initial Catalog=hidden;User ID=hidden;Password=hidden;");

        // Create Query Command
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Connection = sqlConnection;

        // Open connection and execute query
        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using(SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                string app_id= rdr["app_id"].ToString();
                string app_os= rdr["app_os"].ToString();
                string date= rdr["date"].ToString();
                context.Response.Write(app_id);
            } 
        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My database table has 5 columns (`app_id, app_os, date, unix, users`).

Is there a way I can select `rdr["app_id"][0]` to get the first app_id or `rdr["users"][30]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Each call to `rdr.Read()` will return a single row.  Each row is indexed by column name, ie `rdr["app_id"]`

Comment: @MrZander Why would it be returning only one row then? I have multiple in my db.

Comment: That could be a variety of reasons, I don't know how your connection is setup or what query you are running.  I'm just providing context on the usage of `SqlDataReader`

Comment: @JoeScotto  Run the Select query outside of your code, how many rows are returned?

Comment: @Fred 1904 in sql server management studio.

Comment: @JoeScotto... Are you looking to avoid while loop and try to get the value using array indexing kind of thing..? something like reader[columnname][index]

Comment: A while loop would be fine. I just want to get the data from my database and then put it into a dictionary or something to further process it. The main priority right now though is to just get it so the while loop doesn't only output one row, it should loop through all of them... I would think.

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery`?  Only call `ExecuteReader`. `ExecuteNonQuery` is used for queries that don't return resultsets.

Comment: @MrZander Seems like that just fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) is used when the query is not going to return a resultset (like INSERT, or UPDATE).

Remove the call to `ExecuteNonQuery` and just use [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @katamarayudu but he is running `ExecuteNonQuery` beforehand which is probably causing some weird side-effect to the SqlCommand.

Comment: This solved the issue and is very straight forward, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

When you have a `DataReader` you can read your data by using your `column name`.  I've just read as `string`, you can `convert` as you want. Please check this:

```
public class test
{
    public string app_id { get; set; }
    public string app_os { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string users { get; set; }
}

List<test> list = new List<test>();
using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        test ob = new test();
        ob.app_id = rdr["app_id"].ToString();
        ob.app_os = rdr["app_os"].ToString();
        ob.date = rdr["date"].ToString();
        ob.users = rdr["users"].ToString();
        list.Add(ob);
    }
}
```

Please check above code, I've created a `class` name `test` and read full data from the `DataReader` into `list`. Now you can use your data for further processing.

You can validate your data when reading from `Database`, check below:

```
//ob.app_id = rdr["app_id"].ToString();
// if app_id is string
ob.app_id = (rdr["app_id"] == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(rdr["app_id"]);
// if app_id is int
ob.app_id = (rdr["app_id"] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(rdr["app_id"]);
```

Comment: Only returns the first result from my db.

Comment: Basically Op seems to avoid while loop and get record by index

Comment: take a look at my updated question, I included the entire class.

Comment: Please use `TOP 1` in your `SQL`, like this: `query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [hidden].[dbo].[hidden]";`. It will return only one record from `Database`.

Comment: @csharpbd I don't want it to only return one row, the SQL I have is correct and giving me what I want. I just want to iterate through all the results and output them for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

With a SqlDataReader, everything has to be done row-by-row - sequential access.  The advantage with a SqlDataReader is that you can process a very large recordset without having all the data in memory all at once.  The disadvantage is that you can't do as you're asking.

Your other alternative would be to drop the entire recordset into a DataTable or DataSet object by way of a SqlDataAdapter.  Here's [sample code from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static DataSet SelectRows(DataSet dataset,
    string connectionString,string queryString) 
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = 
        new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```