# ASP.NET MVC Model How to get multiple rows from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
public static Article GetJournalById(string ConnectionString,int Id)
{
    using(SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetJournalById", sql))
        {
            Article article = new Article();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
            sql.Open();
            
            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    article.Id = Id;
                    article.Title = reader.GetString(1).ToString();
                    article.Summary = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(2).ToString();
                    article.Tag = reader.GetString(3).ToString();
                    article.Author = reader.GetString(4).ToString();
                    article.Ban = reader.GetByte(5);
                    article.BanReason = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(6).ToString();
                    article.Date = reader.GetDateTime(7);
                }
            }
            return article;
        }
    }
}
```

How to get multiple rows?
I know that if need get single row and multiple columns I can do like above.
But how do I get multiple rows?
I'd like to get multiple rows and return them from a function.
I also want to display the returned value on the view page.
But I don't know how, and I don't know what search terms to search for.
Please help me.

Here is the article model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace News.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public byte Ban { get; set; }
        public string BanReason { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following is the code to get multiple posts from a stored procedure. (Incomplete, unresolved)

```
public static int GetJournalByDate(string ConnectionString,DateTime date)//must be fix
{
    using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetJournalByDate", sql))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 7).Value = date;
                sql.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return 1;
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `while` loop just needs to create a new `Article` each iteration and add it to a list of some sort. And a query which pulls multiple rows.

Comment: @DaleK Should I edit it with what..kind?

Comment: @DaleK just create a list with Article ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744134/how-to-read-each-row-and-value-with-sqlcommand-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it the same way , only instead of Article , use List< Article >

```
public List<Article> GetJournalByDate(string ConnectionString,DateTime date)
{
    ......

    List<Article>  articles = new List<Article>();

    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2, 7).Value = date;
    sql.Open();
    
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var article= new Article();

            article.Id = Id;
            article.Title = reader.GetString(1).ToString();
            article.Summary = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(2).ToString();
            article.Tag = reader.GetString(3).ToString();
            article.Author = reader.GetString(4).ToString();
            article.Ban = reader.GetByte(5);
            article.BanReason = reader.IsDBNull(6) ? string.Empty : 
             reader.GetString(6).ToString();
            article.Date = reader.GetDateTime(7);

          articles.Add(article);
        }
    }

    return articles;
}
```